# Chatfuel not clearing user input cache

Tags: facebook-chatbot, chatfuel

I'm building a flight search chat bot using, chatfuel, flowxo and google sheets.
when I ran the chat for the first time, it worked perfectly but when i ran it again it only displayed the search results containing the input from the first time I ran and not from the second/third/forth time. however, if I wait for some time, 15-20 minutes, the bot works as it should again. I think that maybe the problem is that the chatfuel not cleaning cache or not processing Json answers fast enough.
Has anybody encountered this issue and/or know how to solve it?
Dan.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. instead of displaying the Json results in the block, I add another step and now the json result are defined as user attributes and the attribute is displayed in the block